# How can I track the answers posted by others to questions I answered?

Tags: feature-request, answers

I really like to follow up on the questions I answered to see if others have better answers or to later improve mine, if an answer gives me new clues to rewrite it.

The inbox only shows comments made to me or answers on my questions, but how can I track all questions I have answered to see if they have new answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set them as favorite; in every question there is a star icon that adds the question to your favorites.
When there is a change to your favorite questions, which means there are new answers too, the "favorite" tab will show an asterisk.

Comment: But isn't this a flawed use of the favorite ? These aren't my favorites questions, I just want to track them. Isn't there a better way (and yep I know I'm not a SE dev ;) ).

Comment: @tostinni No. You can set any question as favorite.